# How to automatically reload a page when it is fully loaded in browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html, mozilla

I want to reload a page whenever it becomes fully loaded or static.

For example,
Consider www.youtube.com. As soon as the page loads fully, automatically it should be reloaded. I have searched many sites,tried many add-ons, still I'm not finding my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below snippet to reload a page whenever it is fully loaded.

`window.onload = function() {
   window.location.reload();
};`

**Caution**

This function will be triggered once the page loads and this ends up in an infinite loop of reloading the page